# What are passwords in the 3DS version of SSF4 for?

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv-3d-edition

What are they? How are they used? What kind of dark magic is this?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are talking about the passwords to unlock character figurine.
If so, follows what i found (i've not tested):

**Super Street Fighter 4: 3D unlock character figurine passwords**

**1-5:**

- Gold Blanka: DmdkeRvbxc
- Gold Chun-Li: zAAkcHVbHk
- Gold E. Honda: uUDsTlmbUN
- Gold Vega (Dictator): CgIsQNWbHu
- Gold Zangief: hinsVnebTu

**6-10:**

- Silver Makoto: GHakWCTbsl
- Silver Rose: GKkkXXtbSe
- Gold Guile: qeJkznDbKE
- Gold Ryu: KjckTnSbwK
- Silver Sakura: uzTsXzIbKn

**11-15:**

- Special Akuma (Gouki): uQHkWgYbJC
- Silver Dan: rDRkkSIbqS
- Silver Ibuki: ilMsRBabpB
- Silver Juri: OfQkARpbJR
- Silver Ken: NyosHgybuW

**16-20:**

- Silver Akuma (Gouki): RYSsPxSbTh
- Silver Balrog (Claw): PqUswOobWG
- Silver Chun-Li: tLWkWvrblz
- Silver Cody: naMkEQgbQG

Source: [here](http://answers.pubarticles.com/2077,how-to-unlock-character-figurine-in-super-street-fighter-4-3d-.html).

Comment: thank you, i was just mainly wondering what they did. Thanks :]

Comment: It seems that where it says Vega, I got M. Bison, and where it says Balrog, I got Vega.

Comment: @Ullallulloo Outside Japan, Vega is called M. Bison and Balrog is called Vega.

Answer (score 2):

I found diogum's answer to be inaccurate and incomplete.

This [Japanese wiki list](http://www20.atwiki.jp/ssf4/m/pages/2130.html?guid=on) offers a more accurate and complete list of the Figurine Passwords.

The Figurine Numbers are in no particular order.

```
No. |   Character   |   Color       |   Costume     |   Lv  |   Password    |   Note(s)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |   Ryu         |   Gold        |   Original    |   7   |   KjckTnSbwK  |
2   |   Ryu         |   Silver      |   Original    |   7   |   DPrkMnybCd  |
3   |   Ryu         |   Special     |   Arrange2    |   6   |   imMbAAcbPH  |
4   |   Ken         |   Silver      |   Arrange1    |   7   |   NyosHgybuW  |
5   |   Chun-Li     |   Gold        |   Original    |   7   |   zAAkcHVbHk  |
6   |   Chun-Li     |   Silver      |   Original    |   7   |   tLWkWvrblz  |
7   |   Chun-Li     |   Silver      |   Original    |   7   |   hjekwnEbxG  |
8   |   Chun-Li     |   Special     |   Original    |   6   |   BuykPjdbFb  |   
9   |   E. Honda    |   Platinum    |   Original    |   7   |   uUDsTlmbUN  |   (lowercase L)
10  |   Blanka      |   Gold        |   Original    |   7   |   DmdkeRvbxc  |
11  |   Zangief     |   Gold        |   Original    |   7   |   hinsVnebTu  |   
12  |   Guile       |   Gold        |   Original    |   7   |   qeJkznDbKE  |
13  |   Dhalsim     |   Silver      |   Arrange1    |   5   |   JKbsOVHbVC  |
14  |   Vega        |   Silver      |   Arrange2    |   7   |   PqUswOobWG  |
15  |   Sagat       |   Silver      |   Original    |   7   |   QWzkDXWbeH  |
16  |   M. Bison    |   Gold        |   Original    |   7   |   CgIsQNWbHu  |   (uppercase I)
17  |   M. Bison    |   Silver      |   Original    |   7   |   EebkxqWbYJ  |
18  |   C. Viper    |   Silver      |   Arrange2    |   7   |   xopknDzbqS  |   
19  |   Rufus       |   Bronze      |   Arrange2    |   7   |   nnhksyvbZy  |
20  |   El Fuerte   |   Silver      |   Original    |   7   |   mhikghwbsf  |   
21  |   Abel        |   Gold        |   Arrange1    |   7   |   wRqsWklbxT  |   (lowercase L)
22  |   Seth        |   Gold        |   Original    |   7   |   PkwkDjqbja  |   
23  |   Akuma       |   Silver      |   Original    |   7   |   RYSsPxSbTh  |   
24  |   Akuma       |   Special     |   Arrange2    |   7   |   uQHkWgYbJC  |   
25  |   Gouken      |   Silver      |   Arrange1    |   7   |   awvbqIDbWd  |   (uppercase I)
26  |   T. Hawk     |   Silver      |   Arrange1    |   7   |   tWEsvzubiz  |
27  |   Cammy       |   Silver      |   Original    |   7   |   dfukkvGbdt  |   
28  |   Cammy       |   Special     |   Original    |   7   |   evSkTnQbwQ  |   
29  |   Fei Long    |   Silver      |   Arrange1    |   7   |   MzisXzabBF  |   
30  |   Dee Jay     |   Silver      |   Original    |   7   |   DaRkBPubLf  |   
31  |   Sakura      |   Silver      |   Original    |   7   |   uzTsXzIbKn  |   (uppercase I)
32  |   Rose        |   Silver      |   Arrange2    |   7   |   GKkkXXtbSe  |   
33  |   Gen         |   Gold        |   Arrange2    |   6   |   kGzstOybxs  |
34  |   Dan         |   Silver      |   Original    |   7   |   rDRkkSIbqS  |   (uppercase I)
35  |   Guy         |   Silver      |   Original    |   7   |   AjtsAbWbBD  |
36  |   Cody        |   Silver      |   Original    |   6   |   ATjbYbObru  |   
37  |   Cody        |   Silver      |   Arrange1    |   7   |   naMkEQgbQG  |   
38  |   Ibuki       |   Gold        |   Original    |   6   |   tvfsYAPbDo  |
39  |   Ibuki       |   Silver      |   Arrange1    |   7   |   ilMsRBabpB  |   (lowercase L)
40  |   Makoto      |   Silver      |   Original    |   7   |   GHakWCTbsl  |   (lowercase L)
41  |   Dudley      |   Platinum    |   Original    |   6   |   ZRhsNTMbIA  |   (uppercase I)
42  |   Adon        |   Bronze      |   Arrange1    |   6   |   jeNbhRXbFR  |
43  |   Hakan       |   Silver      |   Original    |   6   |   rLPbyLgbUy  |
44  |   Juri        |   Silver      |   Arrange1    |   7   |   OfQkARpbJR  |   
45  |   Juri        |   Special     |   Arrange1    |   7   |   vvlbccVbMk  |   (lowercase L)
```